# Oracle/SQL Multiple True Case Statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to show SC,DC,DV against each member of staff, each can have 1 or more select so for example eng 1 can have sc and dc.

So need to get

[image]

But get

[image]

I using case to set the columns and data, but can not get the data on the same line

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.ENG_ID, 
            e.NAME, 
            e.SURNAME, 
            e.POST_CODE, 
            CASE 
              WHEN C.CLEARANCE_ID = 1 THEN 'YES' 
              ELSE 'NO' 
            END AS SC, 
            CASE 
              WHEN C.CLEARANCE_ID = 2 THEN 'YES' 
              ELSE 'NO' 
            END AS BS, 
            CASE 
              WHEN C.CLEARANCE_ID = 3 THEN 'YES' 
              ELSE 'NO' 
            END AS DV 
FROM   MAN_ENGINEERS e 
   left join MAN_CLEARANCE c 
          ON e.ENG_ID = c.ENG_ID;
```

Hope this makes sense

Comment: You probably have multiple clearances per eng,so which ones do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use max on those columns, try this

```
SELECT      e.ENG_ID, 
            e.NAME, 
            e.SURNAME, 
            e.POST_CODE, 
            MAX
            (
              CASE 
              WHEN C.CLEARANCE_ID = 1 THEN 'YES' 
              ELSE 'NO' 
              END
             ) AS SC, 
            MAX
            (
              CASE 
              WHEN C.CLEARANCE_ID = 2 THEN 'YES' 
              ELSE 'NO' 
              END
            ) AS BS, 
           MAX
           (
              CASE 
              WHEN C.CLEARANCE_ID = 3 THEN 'YES' 
              ELSE 'NO' 
              END
            ) AS DV 
FROM   MAN_ENGINEERS e 
   left join MAN_CLEARANCE c 
          ON e.ENG_ID = c.ENG_ID
GROUP BY e.ENG_ID, 
            e.NAME, 
            e.SURNAME, 
            e.POST_CODE, ;
```